# Clear ribbon dropdown C# excel add-in 2010

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel-addins

I try to find solution for my problem. But nothing to find. I have 2 dropdown list and when I change value in first list I want to clear and fill new values new list. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy solution

```
dropDown.Items.Clear();
```